# Entity Framework Null in Class Library

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a potentially simple issue.  My EF code obtains data in every project except one class library.  Do I need an additional connection string in my App.config file for this class library?  I have all data pulling from a class library called "models" with one connection string for the whole project. What do you suggest I do?  Perhaps this is an issue with my local database too. Please let me know if you need more information.

Sample:

```
public static bool IsAdmin()
        {
            try
            {
                using (EmployeeContext _context = new EmployeeContext())
                {
                    string user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

                    var adminCheck = (from u in _context.Administration where u.Login.Equals(user) select u).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (adminCheck == null)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogging.Record(ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: I don't actually get an error, all results come back null when there is data in the database.  It's very odd.

Comment: you have to add the connection string to all executable projects (console, web app ..etc) that import the library project

Comment: Perfect, that's what I needed to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your connections string in your main application, the issue could be (though i'm not sure) EF defaulting to the localDB.